# How do I quantitatively describe a system with 2 parallel diodes and a current source

Tags: led, analog, diodes, current-source

What would happen in this system? How can I find the bias point of a circuit like this:

[image]

Considering the LEDs are not perfectly matched. The 35mA are generated by a high precision stablizied current source.

I tried to find the voltage over the LEDs, but I can't seem to find an expression that makes sense. I thought that the voltage depends on the current that flows through the LED, but the current also depends on the resistance of the LEDs in their bias point. That bias point might be different for the two LEDs, so the voltage might be different as well, but that makes no sense as the terminals are connected on both sides.

I'm not getting anywhere with my thoughts. Any ideas? Also, considering those are LEDs, wouldn't the generated heat effectively shut down one of the LEDs in a chain reaction after a short while?

Comment: Voltage must be the same. Current must add to 35mA. See the data sheets for everything else you need to solve this.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this circuit as for any given current the forward voltage drops as temperature increases.  This means that if one LED starts to take more current than the other it gets hotter and so takes even more of the current.  I would expect both LEDs to light but one may take a significantly larger current than the other so one LED may be significantly brighter than the other.  To get around this either put the LEDs in in series or give each a series resistor.

Comment: @WarrenHill The two LEDs are in a single SMD part. I'm trying to measure photometric intensity over current at different temperatures. But thanks for the information. I suspected as much, but the manufacturer must have included some precautions that I haven't discovered yet. *EDIT* not yet in testing phase, just planning.

Comment: If the two devices are in the same package then the manufacturer may have taken steps to insure the devices are "thermally linked" meaning that if one starts taking more power it will heat the other up reducing the "thermal run away" effect.

Comment: See also [Two LEDs: separate versus shared resistor](https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/mp673a/two-leds-separate-vs-shared-resistor/) discussion about LED matching & current sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a search/read of the [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode_modelling) and other resources on "diode modelling". The [AllAboutCircuits](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_3/chpt_3/14.html) page is useful, and this [excellent paper](http://bwrcs.eecs.berkeley.edu/IcBook/AdditionalMaterial/diode.pdf) from Berkeley, plus [this paper](http://www-ee.uta.edu/online/jung/EE3444/pdfs/SPICEdiodeModel.pdf) on the SPICE diode model.

Here is a sample Maxima session using the ideal Shockley equation (not very accurate, but can be built on) to calculate the circuit for two slightly different diodes. Hope it's of some use to get you started. Note that as Olin says, (and I assumed) this is purely Academic, and unless you *really* go to town with the math, unlikely to be of much use in real life.

[image: Maxima session]

Comment: I'm gonna have to be more accurate with V_t and I_s because I need to consider them as a function of temperature, but that looks like a good start. I think I wust just going int he wrong direction with my ideas. Thing is, I need some some predictions first so I can measure the rest and control the LEDs sensibly.

Answer (score 0):

You can't know the voltage exactly, but if you have enough data for the LEDs then you can find its bounds.  The limiting cases are when the LEDS are so mismatched that one gets all the current, and when they are exactly matched so each gets half the current.

The high end of the voltage range is when one LED takes all the current.  In that case, consult the LED spec and see what the maximum voltage can be at 35 mA.

The low end of the range is when both LEDs are identical.  Consult the LED spec to see what the minimum voltage can be at 17.5 mA.

Other than these two limits, you can't know what the voltage will be and how the current will be shared without measurements of each LED individually.  Another uncertainty comes from the fact that the LED datasheet won't likely tell you exactly what the maximum possible voltage at 35 mA and minimum possible voltage at 17.5 mA is, so there may be some additional uncertainty in interpolating and guessing from the information that is supplied in the datasheet.

In a real circuit, you wouldn't parallel LEDs like that, so this is purely a academic exercise.